# Pass arguments from a function to another function

Tags: php, function, arguments

I have something like this

```
  function f1($name = ''){
    f2("prefix_{$name}", $args);
  }
```

the f1() function is called like:

`f1('name', $var1, $var2, $var3);`

How can I pass these variables to f2() inside it, the same way they are passed to f1() ?

so instead of  `f2("prefix_{$name}", $args);`

it should be like  `f2("prefix_{$name}", $var1, $var2, $var3);`

Not that I have no control over the f2 function :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function f1( $name = '' )
{
    // get all arguments to this function
    $args = func_get_args();
    // prefix the first arguments with some prefix
    $args[ 0 ] = 'prefix_' . $name;
    // call the second function with the $args array as its arguments
    call_user_func_array( 'f2', $args );
}
```

**edit:**
replaced

```
$args[ 0 ] = 'prefix_' . $args[ 0 ];
```

with

```
$args[ 0 ] = 'prefix_' . $name;
```

to account for what [Gerry said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054236/pass-arguments-from-a-function-to-another-function/7054279#7054279).

Answer (score 1):

The regular func_get_args() will not take into account any default arguments, so you will need to do something like this:

```
function func_get_default_args($a) {
    $args = array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);
    return array_merge($args, array_slice($a, sizeof($args)));
}

function f1($name = ''){
    call_user_func_array('f2', func_get_default_args(func_get_args(), $name));
}
```